# org.eclipse.swt.Browser opens in read-only mode

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

In my eclipse-plugin project I am trying to open `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser`, And I am able to open it.
But its open in read-only mode.

Now I want to make it editable. How can I make it Editable

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        Shell activeShell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
        try 
        {
            Display display = activeShell.getDisplay();
            Shell shell = new Shell(display);
            Browser browser = new browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
            browser.setUrl("htttp://www.sample.com");
        }
        catch (CoreException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
}
```

How can I solve this

@svasa Editable - I am not able to type any thing on it. Like I am opening `http://mail.google.com` and I want to type username and password.

Comment: @greg I am not able to type any thing on this browser. Like userName and password

Comment: Since I want to open webpage, I am using `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser`

Comment: Look at the `addAuthenticationListener` method to do web page authentication. I personally have not used this.

Comment: Thanks greg. But not works for me

Comment: What do you mean by Editable ? You set text on the browser by calling `setText()` If you want to write something on the browser I think you should first construct a text composite to show on the web page and then write something on it right ?